# Get the time elapsed between two timestamps and convert it to date

Tags: javascript

I want to get the time elapsed between two timestamps and then convert the difference to human readble time (HH:mm:ss)

I do it like this (just example of values)

```
var difference =  1490265243 - 1490264952 ;
```

while **1490264952** is `23/3/2017 11:29:12` and **1490265243** is `23/3/2017 11:34:03`

I get difference equal to `291`

then when I convert it to date

```
var date = new Date(difference*1000);
```

I get `01:04:51` while the difference is just `00:04:51`

I want to get the real time elapsed

how to solve this issue ?

Comment: check your  `time value` `var difference =  1490265243 - 1490264952 ;` its not have  time value only have a date .time value contains [`13`number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) .But your code only `10`numbers

Comment: OP is probably using unix timestamps